# Hazelcast 3.5 serialization with DataSerializable

Tags: java, serialization, hazelcast

I'd like to serialize a Book object :

```
public class Book implements DataSerializable {

    @Override
    void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
    @Override
    void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
        ...
    }

}
```

The problem is that i don't know how to instantiate objects of ObjectDataOutput/ObjectDataInput types to serialize/deserialize Book object.

ObjectDataOutputStream implements ObjectDataOutput but I don't know how to instantiate this object to becase it needs SerializationService object which doesn't have public constructors.

So, are there any ways to create an ObjectDataOutput/ObjectDataInput object from FileOutputStream/FileInputStream for example?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to instantiate them? They are provided by the platform.  If you really want to instantiate them, you might want to have a look at the DefaultSerializationServiceBuilder and create yourself a SerializationService instance and get streams from there.

Comment: @pveentjer , what do you mean by "They are provided by the platform" ? Can you provide any example? I want to persist the serialized by Hazelcast object into the file system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @pveentjer I've found the answer.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
SerializationService serializationService = new DefaultSerializationServiceBuilder().build();
ObjectDataOutput odo = new ObjectDataOutputStream(bos, serializationService);

Book book = new Book();
book.writeData(odo);
bos.writeTo(fos);
```